# Select records by time in interval between 12:00:00 and 18:00:00 on every day

Tags: mysql, date, intervals, between

I've tried to select all records in a table with the timestamp in the dateformat 2011-08-01-

12:00:00

Using the following code:

```
SELECT f.`fly_reg`, RIGHT(f.`start_tid`,8) AS st, f.`start_hight`
FROM vbsk_dk_02.fab_master_flyvedata f 
Where st between 12:00:00 AND 18:00:00
```

But can't get it to work

Comment: you probably need to add the curent month/day/year "13:30 12:00:00"

Answer (score 15):

You've got two issues here:

1. You can't refer to column aliases in the where clause. Instead, you have to repeat your calculation in the where clause
2. Use the `TIME()` function to extract the time part of the datatime

With those two issues addressed, you get:

```
select
    f.fly_reg,
    TIME(f.start_tid) AS st,
    f.start_hight 
    FROM vbsk_dk_02.fab_master_flyvedata f 
where TIME(f.start_tid) between '12:00:00' AND '18:00:00'
```

As an option, if you don't actually need the time value in the select, you can remove it and just have it in the where clause. Also, you can use the `HOUR()` function if that suits better. With those two changes in, your query would simplify to:

```
select *
FROM vbsk_dk_02.fab_master_flyvedata
where HOUR(f.start_tid) between 12 and 18
```

which is a lot neater :)

Comment: From my understanding in MySQL if we do operations on datetime and find row that satisfies condition it will not use index (given it is set on start_tid) I have millions of rows and want to make my query efficient as possible, I could run query multiple times per each day but is there any other way?

Comment: @Ambleu there's no getting around having to hit every row with a function unless your db supports functional indexes, which mysql doesn't.

Answer (score 4):

If you have stored the time in a column of type "Timestamp" or "Datetime", you can select a range of records between hours like this:

```
select * from testTable where hour(`timeStampCol`) >= 12 and hour(`timeStampCol`) <= 18
```

I tested this with this setp up:

```
CREATE TABLE `cm`.`testTable` (
  `timeStampCol` TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL,
  `dateTimeCol` DATETIME  NOT NULL
)
ENGINE = MyISAM
COMMENT = 'Delete this table';

insert into testTable values ('2010-01-01 14:52:00', '2010-01-01 14:52:00')
insert into testTable values ('2010-01-01 19:48:00', '2010-01-01 19:48:00')
```