# SQL where two time values between two time columns

Tags: mysql, sql, date, time

With MySQL, I need to find rows where two values are between two columns.

For example, I'm creating a schedule from '15:00' to '18:00', but the query must verify if any row has an period in use. If there is a record from '14:00' to '18:30', I need to return it to validate.

I tried something like, but not works:

```
select * from availabilities where (('15:00' or '18:00') between start_hour and end_hour)
```

Any idea?

Comment: http://wiki.c2.com/?TestIfDateRangesOverlap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically a "test if range overlaps another range" question. The following query should work as long as start time is less than end time:

```
SELECT *
FROM availabilities
WHERE '18:00' > start_hour AND end_hour > '15:00'
```

Comment: what must be done if start time is greater than end time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TIME()` function to extract the time part of the datatime/timestamp column

Eg.

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE TIME('timeStampCol') BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '18:00:00'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973844/select-records-by-time-in-interval-between-120000-and-180000-on-every-day